# whats the mistake → href="get_permalink()

Tags: permalinks

```
<?php echo '<h1><a href="get_permalink()">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h1>'; ?>
```

This is not generating the permalink →

```
href="get_permalink()
```

I also tried this version →

```
<?php echo '<h1><a href="get_permalink()">' ?> <?php . get_the_title() . '</a></h1>'; ?>
```

whats wrong you can get the feel here →

[Click Here](http://codepen.trafficopedia.com/site01/?s=1)

Click on any link it will not take you the desired single page as expected.

Please forgive me If you think I am doing a very silly mistake. we all were novice some day before we became a pro.

Comment: There's no need to delete the question. Although it's a simple PHP syntax mistake, but it might happen to someone else, so maybe someone can use this answer some day.

Comment: When people start to downvote me I feel disappointed.

Comment: Don't be. It happened to me too, actually happens to almost anyone that is starting to learn. Keep it going!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code.

```
<?php echo '<h1><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h1>'; ?>
```

Hope this will helps you.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you downvoted me? If Yes then why?

Comment: Can you please delete the answer so that I can delete the question?